# Get an Array of Controls in Access Form

Tags: ms-access

Hello I'm very new to vba in Access

I'm trying to get an array of the controls in my form through a button.

My end goal is to press a button and have it loop through the array of controls and ask if it is equal to -1 (the controls are Yes/No check boxes) and if it is, to open a corresponding form.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through Textboxes in access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290099/loop-through-textboxes-in-access-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code like this in the OnClick event of your button:

```vb
    Const FormName As String = "CorrespondingFormName"

    Dim Control As Control
    
    For Each Control In Me.Controls
        If Control.ControlType = acCheckBox Then
            If Control.Value = True Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    If Not Control Is Nothing Then
        ' A checked checkbox was found.
        DoCmd.OpenForm FormName
    End If
```